# Change Div Text From Other Page with JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have problem here, please help about this.

Let's say i have 2 page. 1st Page index.php and 2nd page is data.php

In index.php i have div and not have any text inside this div. Here my index.php script

```
<div id="confirm"></div>
<img border="0" src="choose.png" width="90" height="90" id="choose">
```

and second page i have image at data.php and when i click image at data.php page and class value will show inside  at index.php page.

data.php

```
    <img border="0" src="choose.png" width="90" height="90" id="choose" class="ThisItem">
```

And here my js script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').hide();

    $("#cChooseImg").click(function() {
        $("#test").html(' Change Item.');
        alert('Click OK');
    });
});
```

The point is, in data.php i have one image and when click i want image class will show inside div at index.php. How i should change in js script? because this section $("#test").html(' Change Item.'); i don't know what should i write down.

Maybe you can help me?

Regards And Many..many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in modern browser you can use data storage
 here : http://api.jquery.com/category/miscellaneous/data-storage/

but if i have to do this i will turn into server side
something like chat scripts
after first click you send data to server and in second file you will get data from server with an interval and after get the click signal it will change the class!...

Comment: thank you for reply. Should be done. Thank you again.